# no display in my desktop

Tags: computer-building, post

How do I fix my desktop if it has no display?
I tried to connect the monitor in my laptop and it worked. I also checked the connection in the desktop but still doesn't work. Are there problems in the motherboard, cpu, or any part aside from the monitor that will cause a no display.

Comment: Are you able to see text on the screen during POST, before your OS boots?

Comment: "What's the last thing you did before it stopped working." --Old IT Mantra

Comment: Nope there's no post, the monitor just said 'no display'.last thing I did?I converted 10 rmvb videos into avi using total video converter while browsing using chrome and downloading using firefox. Maybe the desktop was running for 5 hours by then.

Answer (score 1):

My usual 'no display' troubleshooting is:

1. check power button - both on monitor and on computer
2. cables - check connection of power and vga/dvi cables, make sure everything's nice and tight
3. try another monitor (if available)
4. try another computer (if available)
5. video card - re-seat, make sure all cables are plugged into correct places, try another if you have one available
6. RAM - I always take out the RAM and reboot just to see if I can make it do something different
7. processor - when a proc is shot, it won't POST, beep, output video or anything. Try another one, try re-seating, make sure everything's nice and cool (a overheated proc will do the same)
8. mobo - when everything else is 'known-good', what else could it be?

Comment: When you check the cables, make sure you check for bent pins

Answer (score 1):

You know the monitor and cable are good, this brings the variables down to power supply, video card, processor, RAM or something integrated on the motherboard that is required by POST, but for all intents and purposes, all this is classified as just the motherboard.
If you don't have an internal speaker, install one, they're cheap and the best indicator of why your board is not posting. If you have one, listen to the post beeps and look them up in your BIOS documentation.
If you cannot get post beeps, then make sure all your fans are spinning (video card and processor are really the most important). If one or more spin and lights go on, your power supply is fine. If one of the fans are dead, most likely the component it is meant to cool is also dead.
Disconnect everything but the core components (power supply, processor + fan, vid card + fan, 1 dimm of RAM. Cycle through your RAM by testing each stick, one at a time, in each slot.
If you still get nothing, try swapping vid cards (if you are using an add-on, remove it and use on-board if available, if none available, use a different add-on).
Again, if you still get nothing, then either your processor or motherboard are dead. Almost always at this point, you can assume its the motherboard as the processor will rarely just die, unless the fan has been dead long enough for the processor to fry itself.
On rare occasion, reseating the board in the chassis might help (badly installed boards can short out, especially if its in a cheap chassis, but usually the board dies if this happens).

Also, an important note, if you recently installed any hardware, remove it first, then try and boot again. If it works then you either have a conflict with the new device, or you are overdrawing your power supply.

Answer (score 0):

First, check whether your computer boots into Windows i.e., since you have a problem with the monitor, the only way to verify it is through sound. Check whether you get the BIOS Beep sound while booting and the Windows Welcome sound. If you're able to hear both these sounds, then the problem might be on your graphics card. Try to plug in the VGA Cable through the onboard VGA Port.

On the other hand, if you're not able to hear the bios beep or Windows welcome sound, then there might be a problem with your CPU. Especially your RAM or CMOS Battery. Remove your RAM from the slots, then blow the slots, then clean it with a soft brush and then insert the RAM Modules. If this does not solve the problem, try replacing your CMOS Battery.

Comment: 99% of the time the graphics card fails, the computer won't post. Post beeps also come out of different speakers than windows sounds. About all this does is troubleshoot a bad monitor or cable, which we know are good because they work on another machine. Post beeps are useful, but only if an internal speaker is attached.